# How to prevent apps that use internal sound recording from recording app sounds?

Tags: android, audio-recording, android-drm

with **android +10**,Apps or android *built-in* **recorder**, can **record internal sound**.
So how to prevent that. As they not use microphone I can not detect that other apps use microphone.

Comment: It's up to the audio-playing apps to decide if they want to allow other apps to capture their audio, which they can decide at runtime or by setting a manifest flag. The user also already has a couple of opportunities to deny the recording app the rights to capture audio.

Comment: First, what is that flag? 
Second, user want to record content of our app which is paid content so he install these recording apps

Comment: _"what is that flag?"_ https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/07/capturing-audio-in-android-q.html

Comment: add your answer above as separate answer to accept it